# Failed to bounce to type in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the first time I ask here so I want help.

I saw related subjects but it did not solve my problem.

I'm getting error in the line `d.setName(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getName());`

This is the related code:

```
public void getupdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    dogies.clear();
    if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "No category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "they are  category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.setName(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getName());
        d.setUrl(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getUrl());
        dogies.add(d);
    }
    if(dogies.size()>0)
    {
        customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(c, dogies);
        listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) customAdapter);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is `they are  category` and `No data` .

This is the source of the referenced class `Dog`

```
public class Dog {

    private  String name;
    private  String url;
    public Dog() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

trac
02-11 22:33:04.709 1631-1631/truckstationsa.truckstation E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
02-11 22:33:04.727 1631-1648/truckstationsa.truckstation E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
02-11 22:33:05.571 1631-1657/truckstationsa.truckstation E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
02-11 22:33:05.658 1631-1657/truckstationsa.truckstation E/EGL_emulation: tid 1657: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-11 22:33:05.704 1631-1657/truckstationsa.truckstation E/EGL_emulation: tid 1657: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-11 22:33:07.072 1631-1631/truckstationsa.truckstation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: truckstationsa.truckstation, PID: 1631
                                                                           com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
                                                                               at truckstationsa.truckstation.FirebaseClient.getupdates(FirebaseClient.java:98)
                                                                               at truckstationsa.truckstation.FirebaseClient$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseClient.java:62)
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:61)

*complet class*
public class FirebaseClient  {

```
Context c;
String DB_URL;
ListView listView;
Firebase firebase;
ArrayList<Dog> dogies= new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter customAdapter;


public  FirebaseClient(Context c, String DB_URL, ListView listView)
{
    this.c= c;
    this.DB_URL= DB_URL;
    this.listView= listView;


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(c);
    firebase=new Firebase(DB_URL);
}

public  void savedata(String name, String url)
{
    Dog d= new Dog();
    d.setName(name);
    d.setUrl(url);

    firebase.child("dog").push().setValue(d);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

   public  void refreshdata()
{
    firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getupdates(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getupdates(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

public void getupdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

```
    dogies.clear();
    if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "No category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "they are  category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Dog d = new Dog();
            d.setName(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getName());
            d.setUrl(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getUrl());
            dogies.add(ds.getValue(Dog.class));
        }

    if(dogies.size()>0)
    {
        customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(c, dogies);
        listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) customAdapter);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: error is Failed to bounce to type

Comment: To get help, update your question to include: 1) the complete error message and stack trace, 2) the code that loads the `DataSnapshot`, 3) the JSON from the location in the database that you read from (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: You could also use `dogies.add(ds.getValue(Dog.class));` in your forEach loop instead of `dogies.add(d);`

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes thanks but is not fix ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error also says:

```
Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
```

So, add Google Play services or set the correct permissions.

Comment: actually I don't know how to fix these msage I add (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') to grade and internet permission to misfits can you help me ?

Comment: pleas neeeed help in  very short time 0_____0

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) how you can add Google Play Services.

Comment: no a lot of thank I do what you say and I chang my way to simple one and it solved

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?